# Pointing to char in string inside a struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, c-strings

Normally in C you can point to a specific char of a string to obtain a substring. Example:

```
char string[10];
strcpy(string, "foo bar");
char *substring = &string[4];

// string = "foo bar"
// substring = "bar"
```

But what would be the syntax when you are dealing with struct pointers? I thought it would be something like this but it returns garbage data:

```
struct line
{
    char string[10];
    char substring[10];
};

void some_function(struct line *txt)
{
    *(txt->substring) = &(txt->string[4]);
}

int main()
{
    struct line text;
    strcpy(text.string, "foo bar");

    some_function(&text);
    printf("\n-%s-\n", text.string);
    printf("\n-%s-", text.substring); // returns garbage data

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*txt->substring` isn't a pointer, it's a character, so it can't be assigned a pointer value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you mean

```
void some_function(struct line *txt)
{
    strcpy( txt->substring, txt->string + 4 );
}
```

The data member substring does not have a pointer type. It is an array. So you may not assign a pointer to an array. You can copy elements of one array to another array.

As for this expression statement

```
*(txt->substring) = &(txt->string[4]);
```

then the left operand has the type `char` while the right operand has the type `char *`. So this assignment in any case does not make sense.

If the structure would be defined like

```
struct line
{
    char string[10];
    char *substring;
};
```

then within the function you could write

```
void some_function(struct line *txt)
{
    txt->substring = txt->string + 4;
}
```